# Create mySQL query in PHP to generate JSON array of column averages

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a PHP script that will echo the average value of each of my columns and array them all in a single JSON array.

I know that this is how I can get the average for a column.

```
select avg(`sales`) as sales  from `mytable`
```

But I'm not sure how to string this together

```
select avg(`sales`) as sales  from `mytable`
select avg(`profit`) as profit  from `mytable`
select avg(`costs`) as costs  from `mytable`
```

To get something like this echo'd from PHP:

```
[
{
    "sales": 56812
},
{
    "profit": 2312
},
{
    "costs": 324
}
]
```

Comment: [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)  - never form the JSON by hand. You could use a `UNION` query or `JOIN` to get all of the data in one shot.

Comment: You shouldn't need to run three different queries.

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

```
select
    avg(sales) as sales,
    avg(profit) as profit,
    avg(costs) as costs
from mytable;
```

Note that I removed the backticks around your column and table names because they are not necessary and are just visual noise and are one other thing to make mistakes about.

Comment: Then fetch it into an associative array and use json_encode.  I think is what the OP was getting at.

Comment: I tried this, but getting 500 error:

`$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

$sql= ("select
    avg(sales) as sales,
    avg(profit) as profit,
    avg(costs) as costs
from mytable;");

$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);`

Comment: "500 error" isn't enough to know what the problem is.  There's an actual useful error message in your web server's error log.

Comment: Sorry...thought I put that in there. The error message: `Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /averages.php`

Comment: This is more debugging than can be done in comments.  The SQL I gave you should work, but there is apparently something else wrong with your code.